# Alternative approach for Zuul and Spring Cloud gateway while upgrading to Spring 2.5.X

Tags: netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-gateway, spring2.x

We are upgrading our project to Spring 2.5.X and it is not supporting Zuul gateway any longer. We don't want to opt for 'Spring Cloud Gateway' as we need to rewrite all code in Reactive (We have Servlet based). Is there any other good approach to achieve gateway routing and filtering instead of Zuul and Spring Cloud Gateway? Any suggestions are welcome. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Gateway is reactive, but any services communicating through it via HTTP do not have to be. You just deploy gateway as a separate application.