# Alternative library for Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I am trying to migrate a Spring Boot application from 2.3.X to 2.7.X.
I am using this dependency `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul`, but after researching I found out that "Spring Cloud Zuul was the last part of the Spring Cloud Hoxton release, which was compatible with Spring Boot 2.2 and 2.3 Later releases removed most of the support for the Netflix libraries".

(source: [Alternative approach for Zuul and Spring Cloud gateway while upgrading to Spring 2.5.X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70447211/alternative-approach-for-zuul-and-spring-cloud-gateway-while-upgrading-to-spring) & https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/wiki/Spring-Cloud-2020.0-Release-Notes#breaking-changes-1)

I know that the alternative is to use Spring Cloud Gateway, but this library is built on top of Spring Webflux and Netty and I don't want to change the architecture.

Is there any other way?

Comment: There will be an MVC version of gateway later this year. Follow this PR https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/pull/2949